# Из List<string> в переменные

Tags: c#, linq, list, lambda

Есть список

```
var list = new List<string>() {"12", "23", "34"};
var val1 = "";
var val2 = "";
var val3 = "";
```

Как с помощью lambda или linq положить переменные из list в val1, val2, val3. Я сделалю в цикле, но хочется более изящного решения.

Comment: в цикле? и как же вы это делаете?

Comment: for (int i=0; i<list.Counr(); i++){ val+"i"=list[i] }

Comment: вы C#-то хотя б  чуть-чуть знаете? Это не будет работать. Даже не скомпилируется, потому что val+"i" не является lvalue.

Comment: Вообще, сколько раз встречалось желание разложить вектор/список/etc по переменным, столько раз оказывалось, что на самом деле это совершенно бессмысленно и не нужно :)

Comment: @Radzhab: Очень правильно, вам скорее всего это не нужно. Расскажите свою _настоящую_ задачу: для чего вам это?

Answer (score 3):

Могу предложить решение, основанное на DLR (.NET 4.0+):

```
public static class Exts
{
    public static dynamic ExtractIndices<T> (this IEnumerable<T> @this, string propertyPrefix)
    {
        CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
        var variables = new ExpandoObject();
        var dictionary = (IDictionary<string, object>)variables;
        int index = 1;
        using (IEnumerator<T> enumerator = @this.GetEnumerator()) {
            while (enumerator.MoveNext()) {
                string propertyName = string.Format(culture,
                    "{0}{1}", propertyPrefix, index++);
                dictionary[propertyName] = enumerator.Current;
            }
        }
        return variables;
    }
}
```

Использование:

```
var list = new List<string> { "12", "23", "34" };
var v = list.ExtractIndices("al");
Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", v.al1, v.al2, v.al3);
```

К минусам можно отнести лишнюю точку в названии "переменных", но разве это помеха?

P.S. Какой вопрос, такой ответ.

Comment: +1 за за постскриптум.

Comment: @VladD Улучшил решение. В первой версии были баги с культурой и излишне сильное требование к интерфейсам, теперь гораздо лучше. :)

Comment: А зачем enumerator? Не пройдёт просто foreach?

Comment: @VladD С foreach код недостаточно страшный.

Comment: Окей, принято! [15]

Comment: А ещё мно жутко нравится `static dynamic`.

Comment: @VladD Возможно, стоит добавить `new unsafe async`...